# What is the procedure of gaining and maintaining wireless internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

There are a lot of parts in the procedure of having and maintaining a Wifi connection (or lack thereof) that sometimes makes me confused as to what the heck is going on when I try to connect to a massive system of information through the airwaves.

I'm not asking about the internet itself. I'm asking about the connection the ethernet that enters the home or office etc. and the device using it?

**Over-archingly:** What is the procedure of gaining and maintaining wireless internet?

**Things you could touch on that could help:**
What devices are involved? What is required, what makes things faster and what dictates that speed? Is there a system of queueing when multiple devices are connected?